# rectMode(CENTER) not rotating shape around its center

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been experimenting with p5.js and I've been having a bit of trouble with rotations. According to the docs, I should be able to rotate the rectangle around its center by using `rectMode(CENTER);` though that seems to not be working. I've tried moving the statement around to various parts of the code, but it seems to still be rotating around (0,0) when you press the right and left arrow keys. Any help is appreciated!

```js
var MAX_VELOCITY = 1;
class Car{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y =y;
        this.velocity = 0;
        this.accel = 0;
        this.width = 40;
        this.height =80;
        this.angle = 0;

    }

    show(){
        fill(225,0,255);
        stroke(0);
        rotate(this.angle);
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    move(){
        this.velocity += this.accel;
        if (this.velocity> MAX_VELOCITY){
            this.velocity = MAX_VELOCITY;
        }
        if (this.velocity < -MAX_VELOCITY){
            this.velocity = -MAX_VELOCITY;
        }
        this.y += this.velocity;
    }

       

}

function setup(){
    window.canvas = createCanvas(600,600);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    car = new Car(width/2, height/2);
    
    var flagger = false;
}

function draw(){
    background(100);
    car.show();
    car.move();

    if(car.y  < 0 ){
        car.y = 0;
    }

    if(car.y + car.height > 600){
        car.y=600 - car.height
    }

    
}

function keyPressed(){
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW){
        car.accel = -.1;
        flagger = false
        console.log("Moving Up");
        
    }
    if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW){
        car.accel = .1;
        flagger = false;
        console.log("Moving Down");
    }

    if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW){
        car.angle += .1;
    }

    if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){
        car.angle += -.1;
    }
            
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that with **rectMode(CENTER)** you can control how p5.js interprets the x and y coordinates of a call to rect(). That doesn't mean though that the rectangle will rotate around it's center. All transformations are relative to the **origin**, which is located at the top-left of the screen.

So in order to rotate your rectangle around it's center, you need to move the origin to the location you want your rectangle to be drawn. This is done by a call to **translate()**. Afterwards rotate and draw your rectangle at x=0 and y=0 which is at the new origin now.

```js
var MAX_VELOCITY = 1;
class Car {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = 0;
    this.accel = 0;
    this.width = 40;
    this.height = 80;
    this.angle = 0;

  }

  show() {
    fill(225, 0, 255);
    stroke(0);
    translate(this.x, this.y);
    rotate(this.angle);
    rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  }

  move() {
    this.velocity += this.accel;
    if (this.velocity > MAX_VELOCITY) {
      this.velocity = MAX_VELOCITY;
    }
    if (this.velocity < -MAX_VELOCITY) {
      this.velocity = -MAX_VELOCITY;
    }
    this.y += this.velocity;
  }



}

function setup() {
  window.canvas = createCanvas(600, 600);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  car = new Car(width / 2, height / 2);

  var flagger = false;
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  car.show();
  car.move();

  if (car.y < 0) {
    car.y = 0;
  }

  if (car.y + car.height > 600) {
    car.y = 600 - car.height
  }


}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    car.accel = -.1;
    flagger = false
    console.log("Moving Up");

  }
  if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    car.accel = .1;
    flagger = false;
    console.log("Moving Down");
  }

  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    car.angle += .1;
  }

  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    car.angle += -.1;
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```